# Dynamic port forwarding using socat

Tags: ssh, tunneling

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of `ssh -D <PORT> user@machineX` to tunnel all my traffic from my current machine via `machineX`.

I do not need the ssh shell open at all, I simply wish to tunnel my HTTP/HTTPS traffic.

Can this be achieved using `socat` ? So far I've only seen examples of forwarding one port to another.

If not is there another alternative?

Comment: It's hard to say what an alternative might be, since we don't know what constraints you are trying to work around.

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you elaborate on what kinds of constraints might be of interest/relevant? I'll add the required information accordingly.

Comment: ssh's -D isn't what we usually call a tunnel, like a VPN or other virtual network interface, rather it is a SOCKS proxy server. Unless socat can run as a SOCKS proxy server, it can't do what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

> I simply wish to tunnel my HTTP/HTTPS traffic.

You should check your browser proxy settings(e.g. Firefox):

[image: proxy settings]

Thereafter, setup socks5 by ssh:

```
ssh -D 5150 user@machineX
```

Now, all your http/https traffic goes through **machineX**.

Comment: I think that was my question to begin with. I want to _replicate_ what ssh -D does, *because* I can't use it.

Comment: Read about proxy server, e.g. squid http://www.squid-cache.org